# writing to stdout throws segmentation fault in fortran

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault, fortran

I working with some legacy code, but I'm running into a seg fault. Analyzing the core dump with gdb gives

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000007d2200 in se_fly (iq=0) at se.f90:384
384      WRITE(stdout,'(/5x,a)') repeat('=',67)
```

What is strange to me is that I've run this piece of code with different initial conditions without issues, so I suspect that I've hit a memory wall but the core dump analysis seems to suggest otherwise.

EDIT: compiled with ifort 14.0.0

Comment: Recompile with array bounds checking and subroutine argument matching switched on, then rerun.  That line, in isolation, is OK but segmentation faults apparently caused by write statements are usually symptomatic of an underlying problem.

Comment: I compiled with `-g -traceback -fp-stack-check -check bounds`. Same output from gdb. What is subroutine argument matching?

Comment: `-warn interfaces` and see the documentation for an explanation.

Comment: I get warnings for other subroutines, but not for the one where the seg. fault occurs.

Comment: Now work through http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/determining-root-cause-of-sigsegv-or-sigbus-errors

Comment: I commented out the write calls in the guilty subroutine and the seg. fault is avoided. Reading through the recommended link and following the advice, I think I'm seeing a kernel space issue. This would make sense because I/O is a system call.